# Error with Update schema Api - Google cloud search

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm currently working with the Google cloud search REST Api, when i try to update my schema i get the following error. Could Someone explain why?

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Disallowed schema change for previously deleted property: Cannot change is_repeated from true to false. Disallowed schema change for previously deleted property: Cannot change the retrieval importance of a text property.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "google.apps.search.v1.film.titolo",
            "description": "Disallowed schema change for previously deleted property: Cannot change is_repeated from true to false."
          },
          {
            "field": "google.apps.search.v1.film.titolo",
            "description": "Disallowed schema change for previously deleted property: Cannot change the retrieval importance of a text property."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says in the document here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/schema-guide,

> "In situations where you must make an otherwise disallowed change to
>   your schema, you can often make a series of allowed changes that
>   achieve the same effect. In general, this involves first migrating
>   indexed properties from an older object definition to a newer one and
>   then sending an indexing request that uses only the newer property."